# Basic Bootstrap Layout Using Rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new with CSS. I want to do something simple like have a treeview on span the entire left of a page `col-4` for example and several grids on the major portion of the page stacked vertical `col-8` for example.

What I have below is pushing the tree the entire width of the page and only one grid is displaying and that is below the tree instead of to the right of it.

I'm not sure if maybe the dynatree or jqgrid CSS is messing this up or my bootstrap is wrong?

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="tree">
    </div>
    <div id="info"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <table id="grid"></table>
      <table id="grid"></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case `col-sm-8` will always fell down because of `<div id="info"> </div>` that is a block element without any `float` so it run like a bootstrap `row`.
Try to do this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="tree">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <table id="grid"></table>
            <table id="grid"></table>
        </div>
        <div id="info"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

or better (according o bootstrap):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="tree">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <table id="grid"></table>
            <table id="grid"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="info"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't forget to nest your `<div class="row">` in a `<div class="container">`

Comment: this still has the same result as the picture I pasted

Comment: it moves the tree and one grid to the middle of the page stacked on top of each other the 2nd grid isnt there either yet

Answer (score 0):

As a test, I would remove

```
<div id="info"> </div>
```

Divs are block elements, which **could** be forcing the floated div to a new line.